# Uploading image, screenshot to image hostings

Tags: internet, images, upload, right-click, pictures

I'm always using "1 app for 1 purpose". I mean, for internet one and only browser Chrome, for downloads Jdownloader ... etc.

Currently I'm using 2 seperate applications for 1 purpose - image uploading:

1. [Lightshot](http://lightshot.skillbrains.com/) - which takes screenshot and uploads to it's own server
2. [Rightload](http://rightload.org/) -which uploads to famous image hosting from context menu

I wonder, maybe application that combines these 2 features: Right click upload any image file to famous image hosting services (like rightload), and printscreen upload (like lightshot) already exists? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Easy Image Uploader](http://sumtips.com/2011/11/upload-image-multiple-hosting-services.html). It has the "right click upload" and "printscreen upload" feature you want.

[image]

[Download](http://apps.nozavi.com/downloads/summary/15/21)